# Dependency Injection (for HttpFetch) at setRoot in main.js Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I am having trouble getting dependency injection working for my AuthorizerService. Obviously, dep-inj is not ready until after Aurelia "starts", but I wasn't sure how to access it.

main.js:

```
  aurelia.container.registerInstance(HttpClient, http.c());
  // set your interceptors to take cookie data and put into header
  return aurelia.start().then(() => {
    let Authorizer = new AuthorizerService();
    aurelia.container.registerInstance(AuthorizerService, Authorization);
    console.log('Current State: %o', Authorizer.auth);
    Authorizer.checkCookieAndPingServer().then(() => { console.log('Current State: %o', Authorizer.auth); aurelia.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName('app'));  }, () => { aurelia.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName('login-redirect')); });
  });
```

Now the problem is that if I do "new AuthorizerService()" then "this.http.fetch()" is not available in AuthorizerService.js.

Am I meant to pass "http.c()" (which delivers the HttpClient instance) as a parameter inside:

```
checkCookieAndPingServer(http.c())
```

or is there another way?

Can I delete "new AuthorizerService()" and just do (I made this up):

```
aurelia.container.getInstance(AuthorizerService);
```

Somehow FORCE it to do dependency-injection and retrieve the "registered Instance" of "http.c()"?

I can't just check cookie. I have to ping server for security and the server will set the cookie.

I think this is all sorts of wrong, because I need a global parameter that just is false by default, then it does the query to backend server and setsRoot accordingly. Perhaps only query backend in the "login page"? Okay but then I would need to do "setRoot(backtoApp); aurelia.AlsoSetLoggedIn(true);" inside login module. But when I setRoot(backtoApp) then it just starts all over again.

In other words, when setRoot(login); then setRoot(backToApp); <-- then AuthorizerService instance doesn't have its proper data set (such as loggedIn=true).

**EDIT: Better Solution maybe:**

main.js:

```
return aurelia.start().then(() => {
        let Authorizer = aurelia.container.get(AuthorizerService);
        let root = Authorizer.isAuthenticated() ? PLATFORM.moduleName('app') : PLATFORM.moduleName('login');
        console.log('Current State: %o', Authorizer.auth);
        aurelia.setRoot(root);
      });
```

Authorizer.js

```
constructor(http) {
    this.http = http;
    this.auth = {
      isAuthenticated: false,
      user: {}
    }
  }
```

"this.auth" is no longer static. No longer "static auth = { isAuthenticated: false }" which was some example code I had found.

So now "auth" gets set inside "login" module. But this means the "login" module is displayed every single time the app loads briefly, before being redirected back to "setRoot(backToApp)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the class you want to get the instance is purely based on service classes and has no dependencies on some Aurelia plugins, it doesn't need to wait until Aurelia has started to safely invoke the container.

For your example:
    aurelia.container.getInstance(AuthorizerService);
It can be
    aurelia.container.get(AuthorizerService);

And you should not use `new AuthorizerService()`, as you have noticed in your question.

Comment: Yes it looks like everything is working now with the "EDIT: Better solution" I wrote above. That does seem like the best way to not break any dependency injection.